# saveEventually in Parse SDK sometimes saving only on app reload

Tags: parse-server

I am using **saveEventually** in Parse iOS SDK instead of **SaveInBackground**, just in case there is no network available. Most of the time the save happens immediately. However, sometimes (presumably if there's a bad network connection) I'm having multiple items just getting stuck and nothing is being saved even though some time has passed and a network has clearly been available. The only way to push up all stored items and save them is by closing the app completely and then reopening it, and usually this will immediately save all!

I have found this mentioned from Parse:

> "Objects saved with saveEventually will be stored locally in an on-disk
>   cache until they can be saved. They will be sent
>   immediately if possible. Otherwise, they will be sent the next time a
>   network connection is available."

That is clearly not the case in my experience.

I am wondering why the SDK is not realizing the network is available and if I can do anything to force it to try more often. I am also wondering how many times **SaveInBackground** would try to find a network and save, as I believe it will try a few times at least and if so I could possibly switch to trying that method.

Any ideas?

Comment: Have you confirmed the behavior with `saveEventually:< PFBooleanResultBlock>`?  Pass a block that does an NSLog.  You may be right that the save is happening at an unexpected time, but this is how to be sure.

Comment: If you can consistently reproduce this behaviour on devices, consider opening an issue in the SDK repository.